# Script block not work in MVC ajax request page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a grid page with easyui expanded row in it. 
[image]

now I want to expand the row to show details, so the detail page html list below:

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title>谱系信息树</title>
<link href="../../Template/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Theme/View.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Scripts/dtree/dtree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/dtree/vertdtree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        mytree = new dTree('mytree');
        @Html.Raw(ViewData["pTree"].ToString());
        document.write(mytree); 
    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

in my grid page, when I expand the row, the ajax will be trigger to send request to detail page:

```
  onExpandRow: function (index, row) {
                    var ddv = $(this).datagrid('getRowDetail', index).find('div.ddv');
                    ddv.panel({
                        height: 170,
                        border: false,
                        cache: false,
                        href: 'PedigreeNewChart?mid=' + row.mothor_id + "&fid=" + row.father_id,
                        onLoad: function () {
                            $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#dg').datagrid('fixDetailRowHeight', index);
                }
```

But now , when I expand to get the detail page, an error throw to me (firebug):
[image]

I have the needed js file(vertdtree.js) included in the detail page, but why it can't recognize it?

Comment: it is clear that the code "mytree = new dTree('mytree');" throwing an error. make sure js "Scripts/dtree/vertdtree.js" loaded correctly in the page. see in firebug's Net>JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

dTree is not loadded. 
probably issue is how you include script

```
<script src="../../Scripts/dtree/vertdtree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it should be

```
<script src="~/Scripts/dtree/vertdtree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```